# TV comedy about crew of low Earth orbit space station

Tags: story-identification, tv, space-station

I remember watching this series on TV in the United Kingdom in the late 1970s or early 1980s. It was live action and the main characters were the crew of a space station in low Earth orbit.

Two general details of which I'm not 100% sure:

- When the crew spoke with mission control, none of the faces of anyone at mission control were ever shown.
- The crew had code names based on characters from Winnie the Pooh.

I also remember the main plot element of two episodes:

- In one episode, there was an outbreak of food poisoning caused by a batch of spoiled ravioli.
- In another episode, the space station crew had a disagreement with mission control and held a silent protest. Because they were holding a silent protest, the only way that they could air their grievances was to play a round of charades. The crew member performing the mime forgot this and started to speak; mission control called him out for breaking this rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is [***Astronauts***](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astronauts_(TV_series)), a 1981-1983 UK television comedy series that aired on ITV.

[**IMDb**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0081828/) description:

> Mattocks, Fost and Ackroyd are Britain's first three astronauts. They must live in small, cramped space station orbiting the earth. Naturally, these conditions make coexistence difficult for them, but funny to us.

From a user review on the same IMDb page:

> Astronauts' is a largely-forgotten sitcom first broadcast in 1981 about the first three British astronauts, sent to live on a space station for six months. The humour derives partly from their having to live in close, cramped quarters forever under Big Brother-style scrutiny by mission control, and the more traditional British sitcom elements of class conflict.